# Laravel & Vuejs resources[CSS & JS] compilation problem

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

I am using a custom admin template for my project with laravel and vue.
There are a lot of css and js files and I have included them in my master.blade.php file. So whenever i refresh the page (for example, Dashboard Page) the plugins like datatables, select2 works but when I go to next page/components and come back to same Dashboard page. The plugin effects are gone. Select2, datables doesnt work at all.
Can anybody help me with this Custom Template resource compilation idea.???
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i got your problem. It seems to me that you are trying to integrate a template with the project :)

in `/resources/js/` create new file `externalJS.js` and paste following code

```
function head_script(src) {
    if(document.querySelector("script[src='" + src + "']")){ return; }
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('src', src);
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    document.head.appendChild(script)
}

function body_script(src) {
    if(document.querySelector("script[src='" + src + "']")){ return; }
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('src', src);
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    document.body.appendChild(script)
}

function del_script(src) {
    let el = document.querySelector("script[src='" + src + "']");
    if(el){ el.remove(); }
}


function head_link(href) {
    if(document.querySelector("link[href='" + href + "']")){ return; }
    let link = document.createElement('link');
    link.setAttribute('href', href);
    link.setAttribute('rel', "stylesheet");
    link.setAttribute('type', "text/css");
    document.head.appendChild(link)
}

function body_link(href) {
    if(document.querySelector("link[href='" + href + "']")){ return; }
    let link = document.createElement('link');
    link.setAttribute('href', href);
    link.setAttribute('rel', "stylesheet");
    link.setAttribute('type', "text/css");
    document.body.appendChild(link)
}

function del_link(href) {
    let el = document.querySelector("link[href='" + href + "']");
    if(el){ el.remove(); }
}

export {
    head_script,
    body_script,
    del_script,
    head_link,
    body_link,
    del_link,
}
```

then in your `App.vue` or `app.js` paste this

```
import * as external from '../externalJS.js';

export default 
{

    mounted()
    {
        external.body_script('/path/to/your.js');
        external.head_link('/path/to/style.css');
    }

    destroyed()
    {
        external.del_link('/path/to/your.js');
        external.del_link('/path/to/style.css');
    }

}
```

### `externlJS.js` Explanation

1. If you want to delete the script from a specific component, then call function `del_script()`
2. If you want to add the script (JS file) in `<head>` Tag, then call function `head_script()`
3. If you want to add the script in `<body>` Tag, then call function `body_script()`
4. If you want to add the css file, then call function `body_link()`
5. If you want to add the css style in `<body>` Tag, then call function `body_script()`
6. If you want to delete the css stlye from a specific component, then call function `del_link()`

I hope I helped you :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I did as you told me and the solution worked.
Thank you so much

Comment: @0xHttrackers Kindly I'm experiencing the same problem, how did you manage to call these functions?

Comment: @RamearDo how to add these functions?